# straight into windoes while dual booted with ubuntu

Tags: 13.10

I am dual booting a computer to build android but it is a family computer and my mother wants it so that it boots straight to Ubuntu so she doesn't have to choose Ubuntu or windows. Is there a way to set it where it boots straight to windows and if I want to boot into Ubuntu I mash a button that takes me to a menu? If so help would be appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sometimes your bios will give you exacty this option. Usually you enable a botton such as F2

Answer (score 0):

open terminal in ubuntu

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

press ctrl+f and type default. You will then find

```
default 0
```

change 0 to the option you want to be selected as default.

now save it.

Also, it gives you 10 seconds to change the OS to boot. If you want to shorten this to 1 second:

also change

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

by

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
```

Comment: Grub has not used menu.lst since grub legacy and 9.04. You would want to edit /etc/default/grub and after any edit run sudo update-grub to update the grub.cfg file.